# Good, or Bad? 'www A Record (IPv4)' - "website has a CName Record."

Tags: dns, cname

**Question #1:**

One DNS Look-up service I use states: (BTW, moodle.org is not my website!)

> Your website www.moodle.org does not have CName Record which is good.

Why is this "good"?

**Introduction to Question #2:**

The same Look-up service states the following for **our** Domain Name:

> Your website has a CName Record.
>   Your DNS Servers do not return any A Records (IPv4 Addresses), which
>   causes an extra DNS Lookup, which will slightly delay connections to
>   your website.

**Note:** You may well be thinking why are my comparing Moodle with our Domain Name? It's because both Moodle and OUR website uses CloudFlare.

Granted, this isn't a fair comparison to make. So, I checked *Netblock owner* of my IP Address in *Netcraft's Toolbar*, and found a number of websites Hosted on the same Shared Hosting space. Alas, none seem to be using CloudFlare. Nevertheless, I did a DNS Loop-up of one of these, and got the following Response for CNAME:

> Your website has a CName Record.  Your DNS Servers also return an A
>   Record (IPv4 Address) for the CName Record, which is good as it does
>   not require an extra DNS Lookup.

**Question #2:**

Given that the DNS Report for **our** Domain Name states the following, repeated from above:

> Your website has a CName Record.
>   Your DNS Servers do not return any A Records (IPv4 Addresses), which
>   causes an extra DNS Lookup, which will slightly delay connections to
>   your website.

... what change **might** I need to make to our DNS Record? Please note '1400 TTL'.

**OUR current DNS Record:**

```
mydomain.org.uk.            14400   IN  A   1##.##.###.###  

localhost.mydomain.org.uk.  14400   IN  A   127.0.0.1

mail.mydomain.org.uk.       14400   IN  CNAME   mydomain.org.uk

www.mydomain.org.uk.        1400    IN  CNAME   www.mydomain.org.uk.cdn.cloudflare.net

ftp.mydomain.org.uk.        14400   IN  A   1##.##.###.###  

cpanel.mydomain.org.uk.     14400   IN  A   1##.##.###.###  

webdisk.mydomain.org.uk.    14400   IN  A   1##.##.###.###  

whm.mydomain.org.uk.        14400   IN  A   1##.##.###.###

webmail.mydomain.org.uk.    14400   IN  A   1##.##.###.###      

mydomain.org.uk.            14400   IN  TXT v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:1##.##.###.### ~all  

cloudflare-resolve-to.mydomain.org.uk.  1400    IN  CNAME   mydomain.org.uk
```

Comment: Can you whittle this question down to be shorter? We don't need that much detail.

Comment: I think I was spilling my heart out. It was late. I've removed Introduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CNAME is basically an alias to another DNS record. A not uncommon setup is something like this:

```
example.com        A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
www.example.com    CNAME   example.com
```

If someone hits `www.example.com` and the DNS result isn't cached, resolution of a setup like this is *very slightly* slower, since two DNS lookups are required (one for `www.example.com`, , followed by a lookup for `example.com`). So that's probably why the tool you're using is referring to a lack of CNAME as 'good'.

I'm not familiar with Cloudflare's product offerings, but in your case you may only be able to use a CNAME, so I really wouldn't worry about this. Moodle may have a different Cloudflare setup to you gives them a dedicated IP they can point their records to.

Comment: To create some perspective, a dig from our network to one of our sites, via our own dns: 79millisec. A dig on google.com took 21millisec. In the worst case, double it for the double lookups.

Comment: @Tim Fountain - www.mydomain.org.uk CNAME is CloudFlare. So I shouldn't add www.mydomain.com    CNAME   mydomain.com, in this case - seemingly. So the miniscule difference in performance is not worth _worrying_ about. Echoing my earlier thoughts, there is a perfect & ideal setup, but there is also practical & particular one - those DNS Look-up services focus very much on emphasizing the _perfect_.

Comment: I see, looking at another DNS Record I'm working on, _www. mydomain2 .org.uk_ resolves to the IP. Just as _mydomain .org.uk._ points to an IP. In the above case, Hostname www. is being used for CNAME as an alias for the CDN. **QUESTION:** Might I still add _www . mydomain .org.uk A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx_?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. DNS records always resolve to an IP (even if a CNAME is used), that's their purpose.

Comment: The question is ultimately concerning the most optimum record: Seems it might be necessary to add: `www . mydomain  . org . uk. 14400 IN A xxx.xx.xxx.xxx` to the record, as it is in my original post. On the other hand, I doubt this is right, since the type CNAME is set for www. Seems that there are 2 perspectives in respect of configuration: '_if it works, don't fix it_' vs. '_this inconsequential configuration is not correct and must fixed_'. It's my fear of not getting everything 100% proper. I think DNS training is due.

Comment: Well like I said in my answer, the A record will be a tiny bit faster in some circumstances, but the difference is probably not worth worrying about.